# Display featured image as thumbnail?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, post

I am currently trying to display a post to my homepage from a category, along with an image (featured image).

so far, I have this code which grabs the post and displays it on my homepage:

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <?php query_posts('cat=4');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_content();
    endwhile;?>
  </div>
```

This does display, but I have now attempted to set a featured image aswell.

I would like it to display like:

[image: Post and thumbnail?]

I have seen some suggestions such as

`<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>`

but i'm not 100% where to add this.

Super thanks in advance!

Comment: One more issue, I am trying to use my framework to put the thumbnail in a col-md-4 and the content in a col-md-8. 

How would this work? When i try to split the PHP up, it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <?php query_posts('cat=4');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
    } 
    the_content();
    endwhile;?>
  </div>
```

You will probably need to wrap the_content and the_post_thumbnail in divs and style with CSS or use the column classes from your theme

Comment: You can add class(es) to the featured image itself -- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail#Parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, untested though. I left the `args` as an array in case you had others to add.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">

<?php 
$args = array( 'cat' => 4 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>

<div style="float: left;">
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?>
</div>

<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div>
</div>
```